# fadeShow JS Issue w/ Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

http://www.fau.edu/cdc/

I'm trying to figure out what's causing Internet Explorer (all versions, it seems) to fail to load the employer slideshow in the bottom of the left-hand navigation.

I just started working for this website so I'm not fully used to the code for this particular section and I haven't had any experience with this particular script.

It seems to fail at line 116 in dynamic.js, which is:

```
picobj.innerHTML=slideHTML
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nested `<p>` elements (the most likely cause here, I believe) or mismatched tags, innerHTML will fail.